# Rails: load data from seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I run `rake db:setup`, I want to load the data from seeds.rb. But after running `db:setup`, I don't see my posts any more.
How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you simply run `rake db:seed` after doing `rake db:setup`?

Comment: Yes...I get 
rake aborted!
Multiple migrations have the name AddIndexToUsersUsername

Comment: Okay, so you'll need to fix those repetitive migrations.  It's possible that, if you're getting that error on `rake db:seed`, `rake db:setup is quietly failing.  Try fixing your migrations and running `rake db:seed` again.